# How to write POST with field names?

Tags: php, post, http-post

i have this code:

```
file_put_contents("123.txt", $_POST);
```

And in txt will be something like:
value1value2value3

I need to write all POST field name and then value ($_POST['OS'], $_POST['USRRNAME']) like that:
OS:Win7USERNAME:BLABLA

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$f = fopen("123.txt", "w");
$postArray = array_keys($_POST);            
foreach($postArray as $idx => $itemId) {            
    $v = $_POST[$itemId];
    fprintf($f, "%s: $s\n", $itemId, $v);
}
fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try print_r() if you don't concern about the layout:

```
file_put_contents("123.txt", print_r($_POST) );
```